# Waiting for a contract to be mined

Tags: go-ethereum, contract-development, geth-debugging

I added the following code for implementing a wait logic after deploying the contract and before calling the functions from the contract. This is same as mentioned in some other posts in Stackexchange.

```
// await sleep trick
function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

// We need to wait until any miner has included the transaction
// in a block to get the address of the contract
async function waitBlock() {
  while (true) {
    let receipt = web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt(transferfunds.transactionHash);
    if (receipt && receipt.contractAddress) {
      console.log("Your contract has been deployed at http://testnet.etherscan.io/address/" + receipt.contractAddress);
      console.log("Note that it might take 30 - 90 sceonds for the block to propagate befor it's visible in etherscan.io");
      break;
    }
    console.log("Waiting a mined block to include your contract... currently in block " + web3.eth.blockNumber);
    await sleep(4000);
  }
  return;
}
```

While loading the script to Geth for testing, it returned the following error.
[image]

The error displayed points to the `=>` from the `sleep()`. How can we get rid of this error ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like your code is written in ES6, but Geth does not support ES6 syntax. Geth uses [otto](https://github.com/robertkrimen/otto) as its JavaScript VM, which only supports ES5.

You'll need to translate your code to ES5 first. Something like this (completely untested):

```
function waitBlock(callback) {
  function innerWaitBlock() {
    var receipt = web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt(transferfunds.transactionHash);
    if (receipt && receipt.contractAddress) {
      console.log("Your contract has been deployed at http://testnet.etherscan.io/address/" + receipt.contractAddress);
      console.log("Note that it might take 30 - 90 sceonds for the block to propagate befor it's visible in etherscan.io");
    } else {
      console.log("Waiting a mined block to include your contract... currently in block " + web3.eth.blockNumber);
      setTimeout(innerWaitBlock, 4000);
    }
  }
  innerWaitBlock();
}

waitBlock(function () {
  // do stuff here now that the contract has been deployed
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I found that the code is not mowing past setTimeout :(

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "not [moving] past setTimeout?" Are you seeing an error of some sort? Or something else?

Comment: It was not writing any logs after that. I am still working on it. it could be some other coding error I made. Let me get back to you.

Comment: It seems that while executing, the control is coming inside the function and goes back to the main program where it was called from, regardless of completion of setTimeout. I used the same logic and wrote using while and a wait function (which runs a for loop till the required delay is over). It is working as expected now.

Comment: Yes, you'll need to use a callback (to replace the ES6 async/await) if you want to run code only after `waitBlock` finishes. I've edited my code to reflect that.

Comment: Is it impossible with ES5 for the script to reach the end only once the block has been mined, as in the ES6 example that the OP copied from https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/11801/36845 ?